# How can I build a widget area widget using the built in Wordpress functionalities?

Tags: widgets

My Home has a Main Area that consists of all sorts of widgets. Now I am looking for a solution where I can add a custom widget area as a widget and then add all the needed widgets inside that custom widget area. And I want this to be in a drag and drop fashion, where I can change the order of the widgets in the custom area; just like the default widget system. I have been looking for a plugin but seems like it doesn't exist. So, I am thinking of building it myself. However, I don't know where to even begin. What libraries do I need for wordpress widget drag and drop support? I don't have problem building the display (the widget function) my main problem is editing function (the form function).

Comment: Is there any way you could show us a link to your website ? I'm having a hard time understanding what exactly you're looking to accomplish.

Comment: http://noc-aze.gasimzada.net/en/ - I want to have a widget area as a widget in which the Latest News widget is located. And I want to make it in a way that, I can add widgets to that widget area the same way I add widgets to any sidebar/widget-area